# PHP split/explode string

Tags: php, regex, split, explode

I would like to split/explode a string in PHP. The string looks like this:

```
<strong>Label</strong><p>Value</p>
```

With this result:

```
array(
    '<strong>Label</strong>',
    '<p>Value</p>'
)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
$string = "<strong>Label</strong><p>Value</p>";
$pos = strpos($string,'<p>');
$array = array();
$array[] = substr($string, 0,$pos);
$array[] = substr($string,$pos);
```

Or using preg_match:

```
preg_match('%(.*g>)(.*)%',$string,$array);
//$array[1] = '<strong>Label</strong>'
//$array[2] = '<p>Value</p>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this always faster than `preg` functions?

```
<?php
$str = "<strong>Label</strong><p>Value</p>";
$str = explode( "g><p", $str );
$str = implode( "g>~<p", $str);
$str = explode( "~", $str );
```

And be warned: tags can get nested and the logic gets difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to be able to achieve that with explode, without doing something kinda hacky like:

```
$str = "<strong>Label</strong><p>Value</p>";
$strExp = explode("<p>", $str);
$strExp[1] = "<p>" . $strExp[1];
```

I would recommend using regular expressions instead.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how split works. You need to use preg_split with the PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE flag.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick;

```
$string = "<strong>Label</strong><p>Value</p>";
$array = explode("\t", str_replace("><", ">\t<", $string));
```