# PHP Simple HTML DOM - Get text inside rare tag

Tags: php, tags, find, simple-html-dom, capture

my problem is that I can not capture the text within this tag:

```
<p class="name">
    "                        Eau de Toillete for Men, Spray 110ml     "       </p>
```

As you can see, the text is in quotes

" 
Eua of toilette 
for Men, 110ml Spray "

This is my code:

```
$pos1 = ".h2marca";
$pos2 = "[id=landing-submarca-perfume] h1";
$pos3 = "[class=name]";
$pos4 =".price";
$contador = 0


while (!empty($titulo3 = trim($html2->find($pos3,$contador)->plaintext)))
    {
        $titulo1 = trim($html2->find($pos1,0)->plaintext);

        $titulo2 = trim($html2->find($pos2,0)->plaintext);

        $titulo3 = trim($html2->find($pos3,$contador)->plaintext);
        $titulo3 = str_replace("for Women, ","",$titulo3);
        $titulo3 = str_replace("for Men, ","",$titulo3);

        $titulo= $titulo1 . " " . $titulo2 . " " . str_replace("."," ",$titulo3);   
        $precio = trim($html2->find($pos4,$contador)->innertext);

    $contador++;
    }
```

I need use "$contador" because there are others adds in this webs and need capture all.

$título3 capture an empty space.

I need to capture text without removing the $contador variable

Can you help me? this is the example web
http://www.fundgrube.es/es/perfumes/aramis/aramis.html

Thanks!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit round the houses but this might work:

```
  $split_this = '<p class="name">
      "                        Eau de Toillete for Men, Spray 110ml     "       </p>';

  $split_this = strip_tags($split_this, '');
  $split_this = str_replace('"','',$split_this);
  $split_this = trim($split_this);
  $split_this = '"' . $split_this . '"';
```

Give the `<p id="ptag1">` tag an id and put a hidden input

```
 <input type="hidden" name="ptag_value" />
```

with JavaScript you could set

```
 document.getElementById('ptag_value').value = document.getElementById('ptag1').innerHTML;
```

If their server supports fopen

```
   $handle = fopen("http://www.fundgrube.es/es/perfumes/aramis/aramis.html", "r");
   $contents = stream_get_contents($handle);
   $explode( '<p class="name">', $contents ); // may not work
   echo $contents[0];  // 1, 2, 3 , 4, etc
```

or

```
     strip_tags($contents, '<p>'); // should preserve the p tags
```

otherwise use blank ''

```
     strip_tags($contents, ''); // not entirely predictable but can work
```

Should just leave all the text without any html. Other examples:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15281124/php-split-explode-string**strong text**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15281124/php-split-explode-string)

Comment: Thanks!! You helped me a lot!    *
I used this code:

$titulo3 = strip_tags(trim($html2->find($pos3,$contador)->plaintext));
$titulo3 = str_replace('"',"",$titulo3);
echo $titulo3 . "<br/>";

basing your first code

Comment: Glad it worked - I was able to import all the comments from one site to a sidebar in another site once like that and chop them all up. I guess in theory you should run a regex or some kind of cleanup on the imported html to prevent injection but that might be overkill! Glad it worked.

Comment: Doesn't that leave the whitespace that was inside the inverted commas? - `trim(str_replace('"',"",$titulo3));` should get rid of it.

Comment: Hope Aramis don't come out with a product called DROP TABLE users!

Answer (score 1):

It works fine for me:

```
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = <<<EOF
<p class="name">
    "                        Eau de Toillete for Men, Spray 110ml     "       </p>
EOF;

$dom = str_get_html($html);

echo $dom->find('p.name', 0)->plaintext;
#=>       "                        Eau de Toillete for Men, Spray 110ml     "
```