# PHP String Separated

Tags: php, arrays, split

```
$code = "IH9320YB39391Y2819";
```

Please Help, 
How to split a string become array based on alphabet character?
and result json like this:

```
[
{"code":"IH320"},
{"code":"YBS3391"},
{"code":"Y2819"}
]
```

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP split/explode string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15281124/php-split-explode-string)

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. To enable the community to help you (and remembering that this is not a code-writing service) please edit your question to explain what experiments/research you have done and why these did not help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) to split your string. It seems you want to split all the character/number combinations out, so we use a regex that captures them: `/([A-Z]+[0-9]+)/`. Then we use the `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` and `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` flags  to capture the delimiters (which are actually the strings you want) and remove all empty entries from the output:

```
$code = "IH9320YB39391Y2819";
$codes = preg_split('/([A-Z]+[0-9]+)/', $code, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
print_r($codes);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => IH9320
    [1] => YB39391
    [2] => Y2819
)
```

If you really want an array of objects, you can post-process the `$codes` array like so:

```
$objs = array();
foreach ($codes as $code) $objs[] = (object)array('code' => $code);
print_r(json_encode($objs));
```

Output:

```
[{"code":"IH9320"},{"code":"YB39391"},{"code":"Y2819"}]
```